# Macro to hide certain rows

Tags: excel, vba

Column A will always have the date and time in the pictured format, in 1 minute intervals for a whole month.

[image: Sample Data]

My first goal is to hide any rows that have a number less than 50 in column B.

---

```
Sub HideRows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

For Each c In Range("B:B")
    If c.Value < 50 And c.Value <> "" Then Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
Next

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

That Macro works.

Then, I would also like to hide any consecutive rows that are between the first row starting with a number higher than 50, and the last row higher than 50.

[image: After running the Macro.]

Essentially, it would give me a start and stop time in column A for the flows over 50 in column B.

I don't know enough about coding to hide the times in-between the start and stop times.

Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post code as text, not as pictures. Nobody feels like re-typing your code to make changes to it.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant solution, but try this out

```
Sub StartEnd()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim cnt As Long
Dim cntTotal As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet    'change sheet here if you want

    With ws

        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   'last row
        Set rng = .Range("B2:B" & lRow) 'excluding headers

        cntTotal = Application.CountIf(rng, ">50")  'total occurences >50

        For Each c In rng
            If IsNumeric(c.value) And c.value > 50 Then
                cnt = cnt + 1
                Select Case cnt
                    Case 1, cntTotal:   'do nothing if first or last occurence
                    Case Else: .Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True   'else hide row
                End Select
            Else
                .Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True  'hide row if <50
            End If
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, just for the main logic you're looking for:

```
Dim in50Block As Boolean
in50Block = False

For Each c In Range("B2:B10000")
    If c.Value < 50 And c.Value <> "" Then
        Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
        in50Block = False
    Else
        If in50Block = True And c.Offset(1, 0).Value >= 50 Then
            Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
        Else
            in50Block = True
        End If
    End If
Next
```